# как проверить есть ли доступ по ключам ssh

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, ssh-key

```
ssh $user@$server || echo 'no' && echo 'yes'
```

так он заходит на сервер , а как проверить *не заходя* ?

что бы если ключей **нет** то создать их если **есть** подключится!

Comment: Не заходя нельзя узнать пустит вас или нет. Возможно правильнее спросить «как узнать есть ли у меня ключи?» Впрочем если ключей нет, то вы даже можете их создать, но как вы их положите на сервер?

Comment: можно и у себя проверять, но серверов много

Comment: Подключаться cкорее всего придется, если при авторизации не настроена портянка вывода для пользователя можно так `[[ $(ssh $user@$server "echo key_found") == "key_found" ]] && echo "Ключи есть" || echo "Ключей нет"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

например, вот так:

```
$ ssh -o stricthostkeychecking=no -o userknownhostsfile=/dev/null -o passwordauthentication=no пользователь@компьютер : 2>/dev/null && echo да || echo нет
```

- `-o stricthostkeychecking=no` — это чтобы не было запроса «доверяем новому компьютеру? ответьте: йес/ноу»
- `-o userknownhostsfile=/dev/null` — а это чтобы публичный ключ нового компьютера не добавился в «штатный» `~/.ssh/known_hosts` (благодаря предыдущей опции он бы добавился «молча»)
- `-o passwordauthentication=no` — запрещаем спрашивать пароль в случае если другими способами подключиться не удалось
- `:` — это «нулевая команда», которую выполняем на компьютере, если подключение прошло успешно. ничего не делает, код возврата — 0. [определена в стандарте posix](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#colon), так что можно использовать с любой posix-совместимой оболочкой.